# having issues with php mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql, apache, localhost

this is my code :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$username = "root";
$password = "";   
$host = "localhost:8081";
$database = "database_1";

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query = "SELECT * FROM artists";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$data[] = $row;
} 
print_r($row);
?>
```

errors Shown are :

> Warning: mysql_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\EC\pageAndDB\PgnDB.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysql_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=7996 in C:\xampp\htdocs\EC\pageAndDB\PgnDB.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysql_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\EC\pageAndDB\PgnDB.php on line 11
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\EC\pageAndDB\PgnDB.php on line 12

Comment: I doubt `localhost:8081` is really where you MySQL server is.

Comment: Can you verify the mysql is running through your xampp control panel?

Comment: localhost:3306 probably.

Comment: i have changed my port to 8081 in the httpd.conf as there were some issues while using port 8080